# Error while using circle_dat function from GOplot package

Tags: r, list, sum

Anyone has experience with `GOplot` please could you help me deal with this error? Thanks

I am creating data to draw chart by `GOplot`, but it has mistake with

```
circ <- circle_dat()
```

> Error in sum(value) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

as follow:

```
category <- rep("BP",8)

ID <- c("GO:0016032","GO:0043207","GO:0045087","GO:0002252","GO:0051607","GO:0034097","GO:0050792","GO:0045088")

Term <- c("Viral process","Response to external biotic stimulus","Innate immune response","Immune effector process","Defense response to virus","Response to cytokine","Regulation of viral process","Regulation of innate immune response")

Genes <- c("BATF2, NMI, BST2, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58","NMI, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58","BST2, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, CCL5, FURIN, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, IFIT1, OASL, ISG15, MB21D1, MX2, DHX58 ","BATF2, BST2, CXCL9, RSAD2, OAS2, CCL5, S100A14, CMPK2, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, ISG15, MB21D1, MX2, DHX58","NMI, TRIM14, RSAD2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, DDX58, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58","DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, BST2, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, CXCL9, RSAD2, OAS2, MX2, DHX58, CXCL10","DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, BST2, ISG15, MB21D1, CXCL9, RSAD2, OAS2, MX2, DHX58, CXCL10","IFIT1, NMI, PARP9, ISG15, IRF7, CXCL9, CCL5, STAT1, MX2, TRIM21, CXCL10")

q.val <- c(0.000000018,0.000000969,0.000000074,0.000146408,0.000000476,0.003476769,0.000063716,0.001187458)

psc1 <- vector()

psc1$david <- data.frame(category,ID,Term,Genes,q.val)
```

> Warning message:
>   In psc1$david <- data.frame(category, ID, Term, Genes, q.val) :
>     Coercing LHS to a list

```
head(psc1$david)
  category         ID                                 Term
1       BP GO:0016032                        Viral process
2       BP GO:0043207 Response to external biotic stimulus
3       BP GO:0045087               Innate immune response
4       BP GO:0002252            Immune effector process\n
5       BP GO:0051607            Defense response to virus
6       BP GO:0034097                 Response to cytokine




    Genes
1 BATF2, NMI, BST2, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58\n
2              NMI, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58\n
3                                   BST2, CXCL9, TRIM14, RSAD2, OAS2, CCL5, FURIN, TRIM21, CXCL10, DDX58, IFIT1, OASL, ISG15, MB21D1, MX2, DHX58\n
4                                   BATF2, BST2, CXCL9, RSAD2, OAS2, CCL5, S100A14, CMPK2, CXCL10, DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, ISG15, MB21D1, MX2, DHX58\n
5                                         NMI, TRIM14, RSAD2, STAT1, CCL5, S100A14, TRIM21, DDX58, IFIT1, PARP9, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, MX2, DHX58\n
6                                                          DDX58, OASL, IFIT1, BST2, ISG15, MB21D1, IRF7, CXCL9, RSAD2, OAS2, MX2, DHX58, CXCL10\n
        q.val
1 0.000000018
2 0.000000969
3 0.000000074
4 0.000146408
5 0.000000476
6 0.003476769

ID <- c ("UBE2L6","IFIT1","S100A14","IFIT5","RSAD2","ISG15","PSMB9","EPSTI1","PARP14","TRIM14","OASL","IFIH1","ST6GALNAC5","ZNFX1","GM2A","OAS2","ARHGAP10","CMPK2","MX2","DDX60","TAP1","PLAC8","PLEKHA7","NMI","CXCL10","MFSD14B","ETV7","IFI6","BATF2","HLADRA","IRF7","FUNDC1","MB21D1","VPS33B","IFI35","ZDHHC2","SDF4","ARFGAP3","AMOTL1","BST2","CXCL9","KIAA1210","STAT1","PARP9","SCAF11","TRIM21","PSMB8","CCT3","PSME1","LOXL3","EXOSC7","CNP","MFSD12","CCL5","NTS","DDX58","PTBP2","DDX27","DHX58","TOR3A","UNC93B1","MAPKAP1","REEP3","USP18","CRYM","FURIN","DOPEY1","SLC25A28","MGMT")

log2FC <- c(4.91216635,6.655472541,2.375439308,4.209728132,1.722467111,2.049068815,6.490325281,6.822595279,3.923398782,4.732497846,4.575484123,1.705875531,4.923436622,2.60827345,1.76254314,2.735952574,4.008416801,5.258289598,4.044999594,4.736550072,6.172050919,4.282501104,3.208171961,5.033929358,2.399759833,2.050897793,2.790055166,2.013796663,3.096102122,3.652784775,2.967372103,2.228560443,4.116356385,1.933960075,1.794503482,2.271099156,1.759847056,2.185965858,5.620065046,4.060212365,2.260535128,5.199032677,2.039404187,1.594577613,3.590903986,1.695054047,1.661676721,1.800940501,3.198116164,6.019076336,1.544051107,3.604409672,2.027346375,5.798190515,2.577687459,5.508644045,1.524049617,3.069782335,1.588483574,1.610455719,2.708812209,1.585058938,1.958513089,6.07876434,2.552673706,2.330685661,1.751220982,1.657774036,1.803929801)
q.val <-c(0.00062886,0.001743489,0.001946228,0.002447293,0.0027105,0.003306247,0.003306247,0.003306247,0.003307595,0.004652201,0.00517898,0.00517898,0.005507485,0.006212073,0.006212073,0.006212073,0.006212073,0.006524027,0.006760143,0.006760143,0.007247225,0.007302696,0.00745667,0.007540015,0.010006453,0.010711752,0.012223333,0.012223333,0.01383456,0.014768421,0.014866079,0.01495666,0.016387919,0.016387919,0.016399233,0.016399233,0.016399233,0.020236508,0.020357536,0.020357536,0.021222655,0.021222655,0.021880568,0.022493145,0.022668597,0.023257588,0.024246409,0.024246409,0.024611334,0.02501158,0.02501158,0.028996112,0.029529916,0.029529916,0.029612423,0.03013124,0.03013124,0.031798869,0.035145943,0.035166079,0.035166079,0.036048176,0.036079466,0.038971488,0.03979543,0.040820823,0.043375426,0.044479277,0.047088372)

psc1$genelist <- data.frame(ID,log2FC,q.val)

head(psc1$genelist)
       ID   log2FC       q.val
1  UBE2L6 4.912166 0.000628860
2   IFIT1 6.655473 0.001743489
3 S100A14 2.375439 0.001946228
4   IFIT5 4.209728 0.002447293
5   RSAD2 1.722467 0.002710500
6   ISG15 2.049069 0.003306247

library(GOplot)

circ <- circle_dat(psc1$david, psc1$genelist)
```

> Error in sum(value) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: Please only include code related to the error

Comment: I put: circ <- circle_dat(psc1$david, psc1$genelist) then R give: Error in sum(value) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Answer (score 0):

This error arises from a wrong column annotation (log2FC) in your psc1$genelist object.
column name should be `"logFC"`